# Regression percentage versus absolute levels

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I regressed interest rates using the percentage changes for each respective rate. The r^2 was significantly lower, .5, versus .85 for regression pure rate values--not transforming them into percentages first. I transformed them to percentages so that they were on the same base level. Should I not be using percentages for interest rates my end goal is the predict changes in the rates to assess risk? why are the r^2 so different for each model?

Comment: You should not use R-squared values to choose between different functional forms for the dependent variable.  R-squared measures the explained proportion of the total variation the dependent variable you are using, and different functions of the dependent variable will have different amounts of variation to explain.

Comment: ...total variation *in* the dependent variable...